# This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server. - while working wth web Driver and ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to start some test, that run very good on firefox

So i got the next exceptions:
IE9 opened with - "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."

In eclipse:

```
Dec 13, 2011 4:10:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver execute
INFO: Executing: [null, newSession {"desiredCapabilities":"Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}]"}]
Dec 13, 2011 4:10:50 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
Dec 13, 2011 4:10:50 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Dec 13, 2011 4:10:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver execute
INFO: Executing: [fa123e21-3209-448a-b070-2c6d155fe490, getCurrentWindowHandle {}]
Dec 13, 2011 4:10:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver execute
INFO: Executing: [fa123e21-3209-448a-b070-2c6d155fe490, executeScript {"script":"if (window.screen) { window.moveTo(0, 0); window.resizeTo(window.screen.availWidth, window.screen.availHeight);};","args":[]}]
```

Any ideas??? (the zoom is ok, and also Protect Mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to maximize the browser window with javascript (see the last line of your stack trace), but you're not on a valid webpage (IE doesn't like that).  Try navigating to valid webpage first, or set your base URL to a valid webpage so that when your scripts start running, it has something to work with.

Comment: I am trying to open the correct URL first by :  // A "base url", used by selenium to resolve relative URLs
  String baseUrl = "http://lab.xxxxxx.com";

  // Create the Selenium implementation
  selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);      but the IE started with some localhost:3333

Comment: Don't forget to prefix the url with http:// - WebDriver can be picky about that for some reason.  Having said that, WebDriver will always start IE on the page you mentioned before navigating to the base url.